# Android Studio не видит классы внутри локальной зависимости

Tags: android, kotlin, maven, gradle

Создал maven проект на kotlin для работы с rest api одного сайта. В проекте 2 класса Client и SubClient. Скомпилировал в .jar и добавил его в локальный репозиторий командой:

```
mvn install:install-file 
–Dfile=/home/user/projects/my_project/example-testapp.jar
-DgroupId=testapp 
-DartifactId=example-testapp 
-Dversion=1.0 
-Dpackaging=jar
```

В андроид проекте настроил файлы build.gradle(module) и build.gradle(project) добавив туда поля `mavenLocal()` и `implementation 'testapp:example-testapp:1.0'`. Синхронизировал файлы, студия видит саму зависимость testapp, но не видит классы внутри неё. На котлине всего 2 месяца, не могу понять в чем моя ошибка.

Comment: А разве этот путь в `-Dfile` и есть `mavenLocal()`? https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository

Comment: "студия ... не видит классы" - это еще ничего не значит. У студии свои баги, `gradle build` что говорит?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ничего, всё билдится нормально

Comment: К слову, переписал тот же котлин проект на Java, скомпилировал, добавил в проект андроид и там классы видно и всё нормально

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja поправочка, решил всё таки импортировать невидимый класс вопреки ругательствам студии, нажал Make project и на стадии билда много ошибок. Например вот первая самая: ``Duplicate class kotlin.ArrayIntrinsicsKt found in modules jetified-example-testapp-1.0 (testapp:example-testapp:1.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.21)``

Comment: раз gradle все видит и собирает без ошибок, значит проблемы с зависимостями нет. А то что вы пишете в последнем сообщении говорит лишь о том, что зависимость уже где-то несколько раз проскакивает.

Answer (score 0):

В Андроид разработке ключевым элементом является система сборки, построенная на Gradle. Всегда главным критерием "здоровья" проекта должен являться результат выполнения команды в терминале

```
./gradlew clean build
```

Нет ошибок -- значит с проектом все в порядке, что бы Android Studio вам не говорила. Она лишь надстройка над Android SDK и Gradle.

В этом случае надо "фиксить" саму студию, удаляя кэши, синхронизируя или перезапуская ее. Или даже переустанавливая.